# Recuperação de imagens no Firebase Storage "falhando" aleatoriamente

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

estou criando um app em que no Fragment principal um RecyclerView exibe uma lista de animais cadastrados.
As imagens estão sendo salvas no Storage com o nome = Id do animal + ".jpeg". Eu recupero a lista, as imagens aparecem, mas algumas falham. Aí eu entro e saio o app, e todas são exibidas. Aí eu entro e saio, uma ou algumas falham. E assim vai. Quando eu acabo de cadastrar, ele também não recupera, mas aparece a imagem padrão no ImageView. Porém nas falhadas de quando eu entro e saio do app, o ImageView some, ficando como na imagem.

[image: ImageView sumindo. Se eu entrar e sair do app, aleatoriamente essas que falharam funcionam, e outras não.]

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Pets pet = pets.get(position);

        holder.nome.setText(pet.getNome());
        holder.idade.setText("Idade: " + pet.getIdade());
        holder.descricao.setText("Descrição: " + pet.getDescricao());

        StorageReference storage = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseStorage();
        StorageReference imageRef = storage.child("imagens").child("pets").child(pet.getIdCadastrante()).child(pet.getId()).child(pet.getId()+".jpeg");

        holder.ivPet.setImageResource(R.drawable.logotipo_menor);

        imageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Glide.with(context)
                            .load(uri)
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .error(R.drawable.logotipo_menor)
                            .into(holder.ivPet);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Glide.with(context)
                            .load(R.drawable.logotipo_menor)
                            .fitCenter()
                            .into(holder.ivPet);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
    }
```

Esse é o OnBindViewHolder.
No pet, eu tenho as informações ID e ID do usuário que o cadastrou.
Pra salvar a imagem, uso esse caminho demonstrado no imagemRef.

Aqui é o código que eu uso pra salvar a imagem, na tela de cadastro.

```
public void salvarImagem(Pets pet){
        //recuperarDadosDaImagem para o firebase
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos              = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imagem.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos);
        byte[] dadosImagem                      = baos.toByteArray();

        //salvar imagem no firebase
        final StorageReference imagemRef              = storage.child("imagens").child("pets").child(idUser).child(pet.getId()).child(pet.getId() + ".jpeg");

        UploadTask uploadTask                   = imagemRef.putBytes(dadosImagem);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                //Toast.makeText(CadastrarPetActivity.this, "Erro ao fazer upload da imagem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                //Toast.makeText(CadastrarPetActivity.this, "Sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Já usei um Log.d pra ver se as informações do caminho se perdem nessas vezes, mas não. O id do Pet e do cadastrante, que são parte do caminho da imagem, aparece todas as vezes.